How to make eslint allow extra parenthesis in files
I have created .eslintrc.yml file and added some rules. Now I want to modify it so that it should allow extra parenthesis but it doesn't work
here are some different ways I tried to solve this issue:
'@typescript-eslint/no-extra-parens': 0

and
'@typescript-eslint/no-extra-parens': 'off'

Configuration File data
env:
  node: true
extends:
  - plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended
  - prettier
  - plugin:prettier/recommended
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
plugins:
  - '@typescript-eslint'
rules:
  '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off'
  '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off'
  '@typescript-eslint/no-extra-parens': 0


The error is caused by prettier (plugin:prettier/recommended).
Prettier does not have an option for changing that behaviour (as of v3.2.5).
You can disable it on a line-by-line basis by using a prettier-ignore comment combined with a eslint-disable-next-line:
// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
// prettier-ignore
const  x = (((((1)))));

The prettier-ignore can be removed if you don't run prettier standalone.
You can disable it globally by removing prettier.
